# How to give multiple folder locations to cdc_path parameter when using AWS s3 as source endpoint for a dms task

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-dms

I'm trying to create dms task where s3 as my source endpoint and MS SQL server as my target endpoint.
While creating source endpoint,

I have multiple subfolder locations for cdc files lile

```
cdc_files_subfolder/table1/date=2023-05-17/*.csv   
cdc_files_subfolder/table2/date=2023-05-17/*.csv   
cdc_files_subfolder/table3/date=2023-05-17/*.csv
```

while giving cdc_path parameter for AWS S3 source endpoint its not picking the cdc_files recursively.
Should i create 3 endpoints for 3 tables and 3 tasks each?

I tried giving wild card options like

```
cdc_files/*/*/*.csv
cdc_Files/*
```

If i give exact csv files location its working fine. its not best approach to create multiple enpoints for each table.